# How to display result of query outside of foreach loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a file called **AllTracks.htmlcs.cs** which grabs every track which has a 'AlbumId' row that is identical to an 'AlbumId' row which is on my '**Albums**' Table.

Basically, once the query has been executed, it will only load the correct data on the AllTracks.htmlcs page. It will load the trackid, name and runtime of the track. Basically showing the tracklist of the selected album.

I am trying to put a header at the top of the page which will display the album name, but I can't seem to find the correct syntax for this outside of a normal @foreach loop. Can somebody help debug my code to help me with this?

AllTracks.htmlcs snippet (HEADER SHOULD BE ON LINE 1)

```
<h1>@ALBUM TITLE SHOULD BE HERE</h1>
    <a asp-page="Tracks">Create New Track</a>
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Track ID")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Name")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Runtime")
            </th>
            <th>
            <th>Edit | Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      
        @foreach (var item in Model.TracksList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TrackId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                  @{string min;}
                  @{
                    TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(item.Milliseconds);
                    }
                    @ts.ToString(@"mm\:ss")
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-page="./RelatedInfo" asp-route-id="@item.TrackId">Related Info</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./EditAlbum" asp-route-id="@item.TrackId">Edit</a>
                     |
                    <a asp-page="./AllAlbum" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this album record?');" asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.TrackId">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

AllTracks.htmlcs.cs snippet

```
public class AllTracksModel : PageModel
    {
        DatabaseContext _Context;
        public AllTracksModel(DatabaseContext databasecontext)
        {
            _Context = databasecontext;
        }
 
        public List<Track> TracksList { get; set; }
        public void OnGet(int? id)
        {
        var data = (from album in _Context.tracks
                            where album.AlbumId == id
                            select album).ToList(); 
 
            TracksList = data;  
        }

        public ActionResult OnGetDelete(int? id)
        {
            if (id != null)
            {
                        var data = _Context.tracks.ToList(); 
                            _Context.Remove(data);
                            _Context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToPage("/AllTricks");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have loaded the album name into the data you send to the page for render. I'd maybe do something like this:

```
    public string AlbumName {get;set;}
    public List<Track> TracksList { get; set; }
    public void OnGet(int? id)
    {
        //don't make confusing variable names. Don't call the items in tracks "album";they are not albums,they're tracks
        var data = (from track in _Context.tracks.Include(t=>t.Album)
                        where track.AlbumId == id
                        select track).ToList(); 

        TracksList = data;
        AlbumName = TracksList.First().Album.Name; //might have to adjust this to be the real property on Album


    }
```

Now your page can access Model.AlbumName eg `@Model.AlbumName` or `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.AlbumName)`

I think most people wouldn't put database entities (Track) into their pages directly.. they'd make a model for a track and map the database entity to it. One good example of why you might do this is because your track times in the db seems to be in milliseconds but your page wants to work with a timespan. This means you've got a big block of nasty c# in the page to convert it, when we could do that conversion in the back end code and leave the "html" relatively clean

```
//don't select db entity for page 
select track).ToList(); 

//have a dedicated class for page.. TrackModel is just a class with a few properties, little or no logic
select new TrackModel{
  Title=track.Title,
  RunTime=TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(track.Milliseconds) //could also do string conversion here too
}).ToList();
```

When you work in teams, you might have a front end dev who maintains the html and makes it look good, and they might prefer not seeing blocks of code they don't understand in the middle of what they do, so limiting the amount of c# in a page helps with a human separation of concerns as well as a technological one

Once you get bored of writing code that copies data from a db entity to a view model entity and back (Track<->TrackModel) take a look at automapper library